# Remove duplicate according to a callback

Tags: python, callback, duplicates

Much like `filter` work, I'd like to be able to remove the duplicate items from a sequence but according to the return value of a callback.

`set` doesn't allow that.

```
my_list = [{'foo': 330}, {'foo': 560}, {'foo': 320}]

# What I would like:
remove_duplicate(my_list, lambda val: int(val['foo']/100))

# Would return
[{'foo': 330}, {'foo': 560}]
# or
[{'foo': 560}, {'foo': 320}]
```

I do not actually care about the order or which get to be kept, I consider all these data as duplicate.

Ideally, I'm looking for a built-in way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it turns out that there is no built-in way to do this.

**BUT** there is a nice hack:

By using the fact that `dict` can never have twice the same key, you could do this:

```
list({callback(val): val for val in my_list}.values())

# In your case:
list({int(val['foo']/100): val for val in my_list}.values())

# Returns:
[{'foo': 320}, {'foo': 560}]
```

If you do care about the order, the documentation propose the following recipe [`unique_everseen`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes):

```
def unique_everseen(iterable, key=None):
    "List unique elements, preserving order. Remember all elements ever seen."
    # unique_everseen('AAAABBBCCDAABBB') --> A B C D
    # unique_everseen('ABBCcAD', str.lower) --> A B C D
    seen = set()
    seen_add = seen.add
    if key is None:
        for element in ifilterfalse(seen.__contains__, iterable):
            seen_add(element)
            yield element
    else:
        for element in iterable:
            k = key(element)
            if k not in seen:
                seen_add(k)
                yield element
```

Which is more elegant as well but is, sadly (IMO), not built-in.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the filter function actually.  Not with a lambda expression unfortunately, since they do not support assignment.  Instead, you can define a function that checks if val['foo']/100 is already in the set of items you've seen.  If not, keep it.  Otherwise, don't.

```
my_list = [{'foo': 330}, {'foo': 560}, {'foo': 320}]
kept_set = set()
def cut_fun(x):
    remove_ind = int( x['foo']/100)
    if remove_ind in kept_set:
        return 0
    kept_set.add(remove_ind)
    return 1


print filter(cut_fun, my_list)
```